# I changed the tomcat shutdown port, now the shutdown script wont work

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

I changed the tomcat shutdown port from 8005 to 8006 for the reason that port 8005 is already in use by other important process.

The configuration I used is fresh from tomcat 8.5x distribution zip. Only thing change was just the shutdown port.

```xml
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
   <!-- the rest of the config -->
</Server>
```

Now the shutdown script (shutdown.sh) not working. It simply just run and silently terminates without reporting anything.

No webapp was deployed yet except for the manager and ROOT webapp.  The server started normally. I can access the ROOT context and the manager webapp normally.

I cannot find any documentation whatsoever on how to specify the server shutdown port when running the shutdown script.

Note: I'm not attempting to run this tomcat instance as a Windows Service. I just need to start and stop it using the provided start/shutdown scripts.

Comment: If I remember my long-ago experience with Tomcat as a Windows service correctly, then the shutdown scripts (as well as the startup scripts) are irrelevant in this mode and don't work. You should instead use [the `tomcat8` application](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html) to interact with the service. Specifically `Tomcat8 //SS` should stop the service (thus shutting down the tomcat).

Comment: So you need to modify the shutdown script as well, as it relies on port 8005. Surely this is obvious?